# How to echo a lot of html with variables and functions?

Tags: php, html, function

So I got the following: I'm creating dynamic pages (based on the page ID (obtained through $_GET)). My page consists of a $_get check (the html may only be shown if a $_GET variable is set) and the echo'ing  of a page with html tags + php variables. Things like:

```
<table>
<tr> 
  <td>Name:</td>
  <td>myFunction('foo');</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

etc etc etc.

I include this code above myincludedfile.php into my main file with functions include and isset($_get) .

```
echo include 'myincludedfile.php';
```

This, however, not seems to work. Altough the html gets shown, the variables and functions remain text and don't get executed.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: remove echo, just do `include 'myincludedfile.php';`

Answer (score 2):

Change it like this:

```
<table>
<tr> 
  <td>Name:</td>
  <td><?=myFunction('foo');?></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

That way you are actually opening a small PHP block in the template. `<?=` is a shorthand notation for `<?php echo`, although it depends on your server configuration if the shorthand is enabled.

If the function doesn't return a value, but echos it instead, you can leave out the `=` as well and just execute the function like this: `<? myFunction('foo'); ?>` or the long notation: `<?php myFunction('foo'); ?>`.

In general, you don't need `<?php` at the *start* of your file. It's just that everything inside `<?php .. ?>` tags is executed as php and the rest is considered static output.

B.t.w. you don't need to use `echo` when you include a file.

Comment: Here's [the appropriate page of the PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php). Note that `<?=` is always enabled on PHP 5.4 and up (even if `<?` on its own isn't), although since not everyone is using 5.4 yet, that's still "depends on your server configuration" really.

Comment: It is, but thanks for the addition. I hope everybody will be on 5.4 soon, because I wouldn't know why you wouldn't want this short notation, especially in template files. :)

Comment: what is the difference between <?= ?> and <? ?> ?

Comment: @Frank `<? foo() ?>`  is shorthand for `<?php foo() ?>` - it just runs that PHP code; `<?= foo() ?>` is shorthand for `<?php echo foo() ?>` - it runs the code and then echoes (outputs) the result returned. Unfortunately, `<?` is also used for other purposes (e.g. in XML) so enabling it can cause problems; `<?=` isn't used by anything other than PHP though, which is why that version is always available from PHP 5.4 onwards. See also the manual link I posted.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another alternative

```
$myfunction = myFunction('foo');

echo <<<CODE
  <table>
  <tr> 
    <td>Name:</td>
    <td>$myFunction</td>
  </tr>
  </table>
CODE;

include 'myincludedfile.php';
```

This is called the heardoc syntax http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#example-75

Comment: FYI: this is called [`HEREDOC`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) syntax. This is actually a string notation. Because of that, you cannot call functions, although you can include variables (hence storing the function result in a variable in Connor's answer). Also, most editors won't do syntax highlighting of the HTML in this string, because to them it is just a PHP string and not a piece of HTML.

Comment: That also means that this is just a string expression and probably doesn't echo anything. You would probably need `echo <<<CODE ....`.

Answer (score -1):

You will have to include the file like this:

```
  include 'myincludedfile.php';
```

What you are doing, is echo'ing the php file

Comment: `echo` is not needed, but it is also not the cause of the problem.

Comment: this still gives me the same result (edit: exactly as GolezTrol said)

Answer (score -1):

Look:

```
  <?php
  $html="<h1>Hello</h1>";

  function hello()
  {
  echo "<h1>Hello</h1>";
  }

  function hello2()
  {
  ?>
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <?php
  }
  ?>
```

All these does the same thing.
to use them, you can do the following:

```
  <?php
  hello(); // Hello
  hello2(); // Hello
  echo $html; // Hello
  ?>
```

I don't think i get what you need, but try to be more specefic.